# Uncaught TypeError with jQuery and Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am having trouble on my wordpress site, my nivo slider will not load the banner images and display them.

I'm pretty sure its to do with jquery been loaded somewhere else, but i just dont know.

Could some one look at my website, [css-signs.ie](http://www.css-signs.ie)
and inspect the error

here is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dollar sign is not an alias for jQuery on your page. Wrap the code block starting at line 467 in jquery.nivo.slider.js with a jQuery ready function setting the '$' as an alias within the function block, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#sliderNivo').nivoSlider({
                effect:$nivo_slider_effect,
                slices:15,
                animSpeed:500,
                pauseTime:$nivo_slider_speed,
                keyboardNav:false, 
                pauseOnHover:true
        });
    });
});
```

See more info on using [jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery).