# TypeError (or, alternately, ReferenceError) when using JQuery UI with WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui, html5-audio

I'm working on an interface for `<audio>`, and I'm working with JQuery UI's slider to provide the seek and volume functionality.

I actually have an ugly little mockup of it which works just fine; I've posted it [here](http://jameskallembach.com/jamesscripts/audio-controls.html). (If you fiddle with it, you'll want to interact with "Instance 2," which links to sources elsewhere on the web. "Instance 1" refers to source files in the same directory as the html document, and I haven't uploaded those.)

The problem comes when I try to implement this (slightly modified) within a WordPress site. The script itself is all taken care of [here,](http://jameskallembach.com/jamesscripts/jamesPlayerMini.js) and the result shows up (or fails to, as the case may be) at `http://www.jameskallembach.com`.

In its current form, an error pops up in the Chrome dev tools at line 155 of `jamesPlayerMini.js` proclaiming `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider'`. However, this is only one of the errors I can produce with just a few simple tweaks; if I:

- Remove the comment marks around lines 20-61, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slider' of undefined` at line 21; and
- If I also comment out lines 19 & 202, which place the offending passages under `window.onload`, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on line 21.

In both of those casses the script stops working altogether at the line 21.

The explanation I would expect for these errors would be that JQuery and JQuery UI weren't present when called for, but I would have thought I'd solved that problem by adding them as the first and second children, respectively, of `<head>`. I basically have no idea what's going on, and enlightenment would be deeply appreciated.

**Update:** I took a look at [Uncaught TypeError with jQuery and Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272939/uncaught-typeerror-with-jquery-and-wordpress?rq=1), and wrapping the window.onload=function(){ in jQuery(function($) { }); seems to have solved some of the problems, but if I uncomment lines 20-61, we're back in error land.

Comment: On line 155 you have $(seek).slider({}). Where do you get the seek variable from ? if it's not a variable then i asume it's an id/class tag ? then it should be wrapped inside ""

Comment: @rusln: `seek` is defined on line 85 (`var seek = player.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0];`) where `player` is from line 74, `var player = document.getElementById("jamesPlayerMini");`. I don't _think_ that's the problem, because in the `audio-test.html` version, lines 160 (`var seek = instance[i].getElementsByTagName("figure")[0];`) and 192 (`$(seek).slider({`) seem to work fine (but then, obviously something I don't think is a problem is, in fact, the problem).

Comment: Do you call your script after the document is ready ??

Comment: @rusln Yes (line 19: `window.onload=function(){` closed in line 202), but I don't in the the `audio-test.html` version, which works, so that's strange. (Thanks for looking at this!)

Comment: Can we get this to jsFiddle ? then we can solve it !

Comment: Do you have all the right .js files loaded in the wordpress version ? Because the error(on line 155) means that the jQuery object doesn't have a .slider() method. That can be caused because the jqueryUi file is not loaded

Comment: I _think_ that should be fine: they were being troublesome before, so I took out all the WorkPress plugins that were using decrepit versions and had the script add in the ones that were working in my `audio-test.html` mockup.

Comment: @rusln, I just tried putting the links to JQuery and JQuery UI manually into the template and commenting out the part of the script that handled that: no obvious difference that I can see.

Comment: Well,  the problem could be anywhere, so i can't solve it without access to the entire project :/. Or if you could recreate the error in a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be less with JavaScript/JQuery and more with Wordpress:

- First, the easy bit: WordPress doesn't assign `$` to JQuery (because other JavaScript libraries want it), so all of the JavaScript needed to be be re-written, substituting `JQuery` for `$`.
- Second, WordPress prefers to handle including JavaScript in its own idiosuncratic way, using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/) instead of normal `<script>` tags. This was mostly a problem for JQuery & JQuery UI, which weren't able to be accessed properly when they were called via `<scrip>` tags (partially because miscellaneous other plugins were trying to call them that way, too, often badly). So, I re-wrote the script that determines which JavaScripts to add to which page in PHP and had the new PHP script enqueue each of the JavaScripts in the WordPress-approved form, listing the relevant bits of JQuery and JQuery UI as dependencies, which makes WordPress take responsibility that those dependencies are loaded and ready to use (with the exception of the `$` quirk) when the enqueued JavaScript runs.